# Limite de cookies javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma código javascript que carrega cookies em uma página html.
A cada 15 segundos uma função é ativada, e esta SALVA novas informações em 5 cookies, e faz o LOAD de 5 cookies pra váriaveis. A pergunta é existe um limite de cookies salvos por tempo? Pois depois de 15 minutos rodando algumas informações dos cookies parecem desaparecer.

O código para salvar o cookie eu sei que esta certo, se estivesse errado ele não carregaria a informação completa nenhuma vez:

```
static save(cname, cvalue, time) {
  if (cname == "salaXml")

    var d = new Date();

  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (time * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  var valor = cvalue;

  document.cookie = cname + "=" + valor + ";" + expires + ";path=/;";

}

static load(cname) {

  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  var conteudoCookie = "";
  var regexNome = new RegExp(cname);

  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    if (regexNome.test(ca[i])) {
      var conteudo = ca[i].trim();
      conteudoCookie += conteudo.substring(name.length, conteudo.length);

    }
  }

  return conteudoCookie;
}

/*exemplo: Cookie.save("user",valorAleatorio,2); Cookie.load("user"); */
```

Comment: A haver limite nunca será tão baixo. Consegues reproduzir o problema no jsFiddle? o cookie tem uma data de validade `expires=date;`, podes mostrar como estás a usar o cookie?

Comment: Pode ser outro problema, isto é WEB ou um App hibrido?

Comment: é  WEB, só estou usando javascript, html e css